# Bijection question

Tags: functions

I need to show that $(m,n) \mapsto 2^{m-1}(2n-1)$ is a bijection of $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$ on $\mathbb{N}$

I think I need to show that the expression is both injective and surjective, but I am not sure how to do that.

Maybe a kind person can help me in some direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I see a problem: $(0,0) \to 2^{-1}(-1) = -\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin: I'd wager that the OP's natural numbers are positive integers.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin I guess the person posing the problem works with the definition $\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}^+$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For surjectivity, you'll want to show that every natural number is an odd number (possibly $1$) times some non-negative integer power of $2$.

For injectivity, suppose that $$2^{m_1-1}(2n_1-1)=2^{m_2-1}(2n_2-1),$$ where $m_1\ge m_2,$ so that $$2^{m_1-m_2}=\frac{2^{m_1-1}}{2^{m_2-1}}=\frac{2n_2-1}{2n_1-1}$$ is an integer. Since a ratio of two odd numbers can't be even, it follows that $2^{m_1-m_2}=1,$ so $m_1=m_2,$ and likewise $n_1=n_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I can do it. 
Maybe you can give a hint on how I could show that $\mathbb{N} \times  \mathbb{N}$ is numerable according to the above?

Comment: Well, take any $k\in\Bbb N$. If $k$ is odd, then $k+1$ is even and positive, and so $\frac{k+1}2$ is a natural number, say $n,$ so that $k=2n-1=2^0(2n-1).$ If $k$ is even, then we can write $k=2^mj$ for some positive integer $m$ and some odd integer $j$ (why?), and so....